# Bootstrap carousel prev button works only when right is clicked once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a strange situation , I using multiple bootstrap carousels on single page .. they are all working fine except one thing that the prev button of carousel does not initially .. it starts working when I clicked right button once. I dont know what is happening but once right button is clicked it starts working great but initially it does not work at all.. please help

```
<a id="right-btn" class="right carousel-control right-btn-SS-Slider" href="#carousel-example-generic-${userInfo?.get(0)?.urlName}" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>

<a id="left-btn"  class="left carousel-control left-btn-SS-Slider" href="#carousel-example-generic-${userInfo?.get(0)?.urlName}"   role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
```

Comment: When the carousel starts why would the `prev` button need to work? There is no previous, only next surely?

Comment: it will work in circular motion .. which is what it is doing but not initially ... the right button needs to be clicked once ..

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or bootply of it?